# Example of using dashdb out node in Node-RED

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am looking for a simple working example such as ibmiot in to dashdb out within Node-RED. Anything out there?

Comment: Could achieve what I need in a different way.  In Node-RED, ibmiot in -> Cloudant out.  Then setup a sync from Cloudant job in dashdb console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dashDB output node you can find more information at https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/02/03/welcome-sqldb-dashdb-nodes-nodered-family/

Comment: This link is very useful for understanding how it works.  Still looking for an example from someone who got it actually working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table in your dashDB with column names as "COL1" and "COL2", you should just feed the dashDB out node with a msg.payload containing fields named COL1 and COL2. Also, I have configured the dashDB out node to have the schema name in front of the table name, like SCHEMA1.TABLE1 . I'd suggest you try an inject node with a dashDB out node and see if it works as you'd expect. Good luck!